# UISlider Disappeared in iOS 8.3

Tags: xcode6, uislider, ios8.3

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 40)];
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

The problem is that, I cannot view UISlider at all but I can still drag it. I have to guess the position and drag.

The compile environment is based on ios 6 sdk (mandatory because my app doesn't use flat yet)
Does anybody know how to fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: As a workaround, try setting the minimumTrackTintColor, maximumTrackTintColor, and thumbTrackTintColor.

Comment: Not a solution but gave you filed a bug report with Apple? My app is having the same issue, typically they resolve stuff like this with the next release.

Comment: I revisited an old project to fix this (among other things that iOS8 broke), installed from latest Xcode and the problem wasn't there anymore. Maybe it was an iOS bug that they fixed.

Comment: @DenverCoder9 did you have to recompile?

Comment: @SaKKosama it was a long time after the previous install on that device, so yes it was recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

I've also experienced this with an iOS 6.1 application running on iOS 8.3.

It appears that Apple have cleaned up the image resources which are for the old iOS appearance. I'm not sure if this was a mistake or intentional.

I found a solution to the issue using the methods provided to customise the appearance of the control which are detailed in the [UISlider class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/).

Here's my code:

```
[self.myControl setThumbImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thumb.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myControl setMaximumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.myControl setMinimumTrackImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"highlight.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I was able to re-create the standard appearance relatively easily.

I hope this helps.